# Bluetoothctl without any user interaction

Tags: linux, bluetooth, agent, a2dp, hfp

Right now I can successfully pair and connect a phone to my machine without any user interaction in this way:

```
$bluetoothctl
#power on
#discoverable on
#pairable on
#agent NoInputNoOutput
#default-agent
```

from my phone I search for the BT device and it pairs and connectly automatically. Now I have two problems:

1. it still asks to authorize services:

   > Authorize service
   >
   > [agent] Authorize service 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (yes/no):

but this is not good because I've specified `NoInputNoOutput`!

2. how to trust a device? It's enough to type `trust` but I need to do this automatically for the same reason.

In general, is there any reliable C++ library to handle bluetooth connections and common profiles like A2DP and HFP?

Comment: I used the `simple-agent` test script and removed the ask confirmation.

Comment: Can you give us more details ? i have same problem too

Comment: I did try simple-agent , it works only once when I reboot the bluetooth device but it does not auto-trust other devices and I have to re-boot. any solution with bluetoothctl?

Answer (score 2):

I used bt-agent with NoInputNoOutput capabilities and that didn't ask for any permissions for A2DP and HFPprofiles.

```
bt-agent --capability=NoInputNoOutput
```

[check the link for more details.](https://www.kynetics.com/docs/2018/pairing_agents_bluez/)
https://www.kynetics.com/docs/2018/pairing_agents_bluez/